# Error "then" * FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.then((value)*

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Hello i get error "then", when i add this code for fetching posts from firebase, not sure how to fix this..

```
 void initState() {
   super.initState();

   FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.then((value) {
     print("got user");
     FirebaseFirestore.instance
         .collection('/profile')
         .doc(value.uid)
         .get()
         .then((uservalue) {
       savedImages = UserModel.fromJson(uservalue.data()).savedImagesPosts;
       savedText = UserModel.fromJson(uservalue.data()).savedTextPosts;
       setState(() {});
       print("got list");
       print(savedImages);
     });
   });
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser` is a getter that will return the user or null if there is no current user. You can't call then on it.

If what you want to do is run some code when a user logs in:

```
FirebaseAuth.instance.userChanges().listen((user) {
  if (user != null) {
    // do something.
  }
});
```

Comment: @ComaXDEA1 what does the error say??

Comment: is fixed, i just needed to change ".doc(value.uid)" to .doc(user.uid), and error was gone.. Thank you once again..